# Load only some elements of a nested collection efficiently with LINQ

Tags: linq, ef-core-6.0

I have the following LINQ query (using EF Core 6 and MS SQL Server):

```
var resultSet = dbContext.Systems
            .Include(system => system.Project)
            .Include(system => system.Template.Type)
            .Select(system => new
            {
                System = system,
                TemplateText = system.Template.TemplateTexts.FirstOrDefault(templateText => templateText.Language == locale.LanguageIdentifier),
                TypeText = system.Template.Type.TypeTexts.FirstOrDefault(typeText => typeText.Language == locale.LanguageIdentifier)
            })
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.System.Id == request.Id);
```

The requirement is to retrieve the system matching the requested ID and load its project, template and template's type info. The template has multiple TemplateTexts (one for each translated language) but I only want to load the one matching the requested locale, same deal with the TypeTexts elements of the template's type.

The LINQ query above does that in one query and it gets converted to the following SQL query (I edited the SELECT statements to use * instead of the long list of columns generated):

```
SELECT [t1].*, [t2].*, [t5].*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) [p].*, [t].*, [t0].*
    FROM [Systems] AS [p]
    LEFT JOIN [Templates] AS [t] ON [p].[TemplateId] = [t].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [Types] AS [t0] ON [t].[TypeId] = [t0].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [Projects] AS [p0] ON [p].[Project_ProjectId] = [p0].[ProjectId]
    WHERE [p].[SystemId] = @__request_Id_1
) AS [t1]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t3].*
    FROM (
        SELECT [t4].*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [t4].[ReferenceId] ORDER BY [t4].[Id]) AS [row]
        FROM [TemplateTexts] AS [t4]
        WHERE [t4].[Language] = @__locale_LanguageIdentifier_0
    ) AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[row] <= 1
) AS [t2] ON [t1].[Id] = [t2].[ReferenceId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t6].*
    FROM (
        SELECT [t7].*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [t7].[ReferenceId] ORDER BY [t7].[Id]) AS [row]
        FROM [TypeTexts] AS [t7]
        WHERE [t7].[Language] = @__locale_LanguageIdentifier_0
    ) AS [t6]
    WHERE [t6].[row] <= 1
) AS [t5] ON [t1].[Id0] = [t5].[ReferenceId]
```

which is not bad, it's not a super complicated query, but I feel like my requirement can be solved with a much simpler SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Systems] AS [p]
JOIN [Templates] AS [t] ON [p].[TemplateId] = [t].[Id]
JOIN [TemplateTexts] AS [tt] ON [p].[TemplateId] = [tt].[ReferenceId]
JOIN [Types] AS [ty] ON [t].[TypeId] = [ty].[Id]
JOIN [TemplateTexts] AS [tyt] ON [ty].[Id] = [tyt].[ReferenceId]
WHERE [p].[SystemId] = @systemId and tt.[Language] = 2 and tyt.[Language] = 2
```

My question is: is there a different/simpler LINQ expression (either in Method syntax or Query syntax) that produces the same result (get all info in one go) because ideally I'd like to not have to have an anonymous object where the filtered sub-collections are aggregated. For even more brownie points, it'd be great if the generated SQL would be simpler/closer to what I think would be a simple query.

Comment: Why do you use `Include` instead of `Join`? [Entity Framework Joining](https://entityframework.net/joining)

Comment: Two queries gives different results, are you sure in correctness of second query?  I'll prepare sample, but I'm worrying about correctness of the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a different/simpler LINQ expression (...) that produces the same result

Yes (maybe) and no.

No, because you're querying `dbContext.Systems`, therefore EF will return all systems that match your filter, also when they don't have `TemplateTexts` etc. That's why it has to generate outer joins. EF is not aware of your apparent intention to skip systems without these nested data or of any guarantee that these systems don't occur in the database. (Which you seem to assume, seeing the second query).

That accounts for the left joins to subqueries.

These subqueries are generated because of `FirstOrDefault`. In SQL it always requires some sort of subquery to get "first" records of one-to-many relationships. This `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` construction is actually quite efficient. Your second query doesn't have any notion of "first" records. It'll probably return different data.

Yes (maybe) because you also `Include` data. I'm not sure why. Some people seem to think `Include` is necessary to make subsequent projections (`.Select`) work, but it isn't. If that's your reason to use `Include`s then you can remove them and thus remove the first couple of joins.

OTOH you also `Include` `system.Project` which is not in the projection, so you seem to have added the `Include`s deliberately. And in this case they have effect, because the entire entity `system` is in the projection, otherwise EF would ignore them.

If you need the `Include`s then again, EF has to generate outer joins for the reason mentioned above.

EF decides to handle the `Include`s and projections separately, while hand-crafted SQL, aided by prior knowledge of the data could do that more efficiently. There's no way to affect that behavior though.

Comment: You're right, my simple query didn't consider the case that there might be no translations for the given language. And yes, the Includes are intended and needed to eager-load properties of the project (et al.) to be used later

Comment: And I didn't even mention that LINQ is also an expression of the client-side object graph that is to be built from the SQL result set. No doubt, it would be possible to write a more efficient query (even as LINQ) that gets the same *result set*, but in doing so loses the rich object graph. In general, people criticizing SQL generated by ORM's often forget this aspect. ORMs have to balance between good SQL and expressiveness, which makes SQL translation much harder. BTW, EF 6 core is infinitely better than earlier versions. Maybe even the best LINQ-based ORM now when it comes to generating SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This LINQ query is close to your SQL, but I'm afraid of correctness of the result:

```cs
var resultSet = 
    (from system in dbContext.Systems
    from templateText in system.Template.TemplateTexts
    where templateText.Language == locale.LanguageIdentifier
    from typeText in system.Template.Type.TypeTexts
    where typeText.Language == locale.LanguageIdentifier
    select new
    {
        System = system,
        TemplateText = templateText
        TypeText = typeText
    })
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.System.Id == request.Id);
```

Comment: My LINQ query does what I need to: retrieve a system and it's template and the template's texts (only the text in the desired language, if a text for that language exists). As the accepted answer says, in my simple query, I didn't consider the case that the passed language could have no matched rows, so LINQ is doing the right thing